# AJAX/jQuery result not printing out

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm very new to AJAX and I'm trying to use console.log data from a JSON file. I have two `<input type="number">` elements and one `<select>` element in my HTML file, for latitude, longitude and language, and I have given the number elements default values, e.g. `<input type="number" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="61.9820" min="-90" max="90" step="0.0001">`. The button has an id of "btn".

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    console.log('timezone is pressed');

    $.ajax({
        
        url: "timezone.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            lat: $('#lat').val(),
            lng: $('#lng').val(),
            lang: $('#lang').val()
        }),
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
   });
});
```

The first console.log statement prints but the stringified JSON does not. I have looked at W3Schools, read the documentation and looked at an example which I'm trying to follow and I can't find where I'm going wrong

Comment: Use your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors at all on the browser console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: In addition to David's questions, what's going on in your `timezone.php`?

Comment: I just looked at the network tab (thank you for telling me to look here! this is the first time I've ever used it and it's been so helpful!) and it's an issue with my PHP file. The PHP uses this API http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&lang=' . $_REQUEST['lang']; So the lat, lng and lang were supposed to be from the form but in the network tab I get this: {message: "missing parameter ", value: 14}

Comment: @Naz1706: In that case you need to debug and correct your server-side code.  The code shown is working as expected.  (Though you can improve it by adding an `error` callback to notify you if it fails, just so you can more easily catch issues.)